# Problema con un programa en php

Tags: php

Buenas lo que quiero conseguir es hacer un programa en php utilizando el método mt_rand(), cuando saque ese metodo un 3 tiene que para de ejecutarse pero no lo consigo esto es lo que tengo:

````
<?php

$numerosAleatorios = mt_rand();
$numeroParar = 3;

while($numerosAleatorios != $numeroParar){
        echo $numerosAleatorios;
}

?>```

lo que quiero conseguir es esto, cuando la serie sea un 3 que se deje de ejecutar y pare.

adjunto foto: https://imgur.com/a/HgyPXOb
````

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para aclarar la pregunta. Faltan muchos detalles importantes que has dicho en comentarios. Por ejemplo, que no deben ser más de 15 números. En ese caso, ¿qué debe ocurrir si el bucle pasa por 15 valores y aún no se ha generado un 3? En el ejemplo pones valores pequeños como valores deseados, pero `mt_rand`  te puede generar valores enormes, ¿se admisibles también esos valores? Y surgen más dudas, ¿tiene que ser con `mt_rand()`? ¿se podría usar una función para resolver el problema?, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te ha faltado la línea donde se asigna el nuevo número aleatorio.
Este debe estar dentro del bucle para que pueda ser asignado hasta encontrar el que coincida con la comparación.

```
    
    $numerosAleatorios = mt_rand();
    $numeroParar = 3;
    
    while($numerosAleatorios != $numeroParar){
            echo $numerosAleatorios;
            //asignar un nuevo número a la variable
            $numerosAleatorios = mt_rand();
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: no me sale correctamente lo que quiero conseguir es esto.

https://imgur.com/a/HgyPXOb

Comment: Entonces lo que debes hacer es enviar parámetros a la función mt_rand(1,9) para que devuelva valores entre esos rangos de números como indica la documentación https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mt-rand.php y agregar un echo después del while para que imprima el último número (que va a ser el 3).

Comment: @DanielGutierrez al usar mt_rand() sin parámetros lo que te va a traer por defecto es valores aleatorios entre 0 y 2147483647. Al enviar parámetros mt_rand(1,9) traerá los números comprendidos e incluidos del 1 al 9.

Answer (score 0):

Para que esto pase tienes que meter el $numerosAleatorios = mt_rand(); dentro del while, si no nunca se va a ejecutar y si no se ejecuta no cambia el valor de la variable $numerosAleatorios, quedaría así:

```php
$numerosAleatorios = mt_rand();
$numeroParar = 3;

while($numerosAleatorios != $numeroParar){
    echo $numerosAleatorios;
    //before execute while condition again change value for the var
    $numerosAleatorios = mt_rand();
}
```

Comment: no me sale correctamente lo que quiero conseguir es esto.

https://imgur.com/a/HgyPXOb

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no se aconseja, puedes usar la instruccion break de esta  forma

```
$numerosAleatorios = mt_rand();
while ($numerosAleatorios) {
    echo $numerosAleatorios;
    if ($numerosAleatorios == 3) {
        break;    
    }
}

//Salida: x x x x .... x 3
```

Al ejecutarla, sale inmediatamente del bucle y el último número imprimido será siempre el 3.

Comment: Otra opción sería utilizar la estructura do while en vez de while.

Comment: necesito que se muestre el tres y luego se acabe la ejecución, y que sean máximo unos 15 números

Comment: Solo faltaria añádir un contador y que se detenga cuando llegue a 15

Comment: No me funciona sigue ejecutando el programa solo que no te imprime nunca un 3